# Replace the word blank with 0 in card visualisation Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have my data say table "info" -

| sl.no | zone | type | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | east | typeA | 223288 |
| 02 | east | typeB | 8897 |
| 03 | east | typeC | 2219 |
| 04 | east | typeD | 7628 |
| 05 | north | typeB | 10900 |
| 06 | north | typeC | 5998 |

In this data there are two zones east and north, and 4 types - A,B,C & D. Type A & D dosnt have north zone . In the visualisation(card), if I select north zone with type A and D their cost shows blank(according to the data which is correct). so what I want is  where the zone is missing i want their cost to show 0 rather than showing written  "blank". If its possible to do so please help me to get it.

Comment: You can use COALESCE formula  -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/coalesce-function-dax

Answer (score 0):

Use this to measure and change it with your appropriate value in your table:

```
Measure = IF(ISBLANK(MAX([type])),"0",MAX([type]))
```